# Intuit API : Unable to retrieve Error Code

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

Am implementing the exception handling for the Intuit Customer Account Data API in my application. I get a "null" for the Error code but when I check through the API explorer, I am  able to see the error code and message. How do I access this through the AggregationCategorizationException object?

Comment: Please mention if you are using java/.net sdk.

Comment: Hi Manas..we're using the .NET MVC SDK.

Comment: Which version of the SDK.  The early version of the SDK didn't display the Error code but since has been revised.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using **IPP .Net SDK for Customer Account Data 1.4.0** or later.

There was an update to "provide detailed error codes and messages". See release notes here:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits/0250.net_cad_devkit_1.0/release_notes

If you can't/don't want to upgrade, you could consider using reflection to access the private information in the AggregationCategorizationException object. I know for 1.3 the information was in the object, just private.